# I want my contourf semi-transparent, but my colorbar not

Tags: python, matplotlib

The colorbar takes the same transparency as the contourf-plot which I've placed over an image.

I can achieve a non-transparent colorbar by adding a fake contourf plot without transparency at the lowest "zorder"-location, but I guess there is a proper way?

This gives me a semi-transparent colorbar:

```
cs = m.contourf(xv,yv,zi,zorder=4,alpha=0.7,origin="lower")
cbar = m.colorbar(cs,location='right',pad="5%")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, but there's no particular method devoted to just that. (Perhaps there should be.)  Instead, you can manually modify the `alpha` value of `cbar.solids`.

For example, let's demonstrate the general problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='gist_earth', alpha=0.5)

cbar = fig.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

And then if we change the transparency of `cbar.solids`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='gist_earth', alpha=0.5)

cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.solids.set(alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

On a side note, if you were working with a transparent `contour` instead of `contourf`, you might want to modify the `alpha` value of all of `cbar.lines`, as well.

Comment: If yout use `extend` in fig.colorbar the tip is still transparent. Any ideas?